# comparing two lists of filenames in drools and display the list of file added/deleted

Tags: drools

im trying to compare the list of files in a folder at two different instances. im passing these two lists fileOld (list of files at time t1) and fileNew(list of files at time t2) to the rule resource. my rules file should compare these two lists & if they are not equal it should print the list of files added/deleted. how to do this in drools?

Comment: OP should show clearly the Java code implementing the participating facts, and describe what fact data is inserted into working memory. Until then: -1

Answer (score 1):

```
rule complist
when
  $listOne: List()
  $listTwo: List( this != $listOne, ! this.equals( $listOne )
then
  ... write Java code to display the differences
end
```

Note that you should wrap the Lists into fact objects that identify the lists or add a date, otherwise you don't know which is which, and the output will appear twice.

Comment: this is what i have..

rule "files are equal"
 
    when 
        FileData(fileOld == fileNew)        
        
    then
       System.out.println("files are equal");
       

end

rule "files not equal"

  when
        not FileData(fileOld == fileNew)

  then
       what to do here to print the files added/deleted..

Comment: What is "FileData"? "fileOld"? "fileNew"? - You can't simply post a handfull of identifiers and expect people to guess the rest.

Comment: FileData is a class with two members fileOld and fileNew (list of strings) with getters,setters and constructor. i hav another class which monitors a folder and creates two lists fileOld(list of files at time t1) and fileNew(list of files at time t2) and these two lists are passed to FileData class. now i should compare these two lists in my rules.. is it clear now?